# angularjs strap datepicker how to set date

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use [angular strap datepicker](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/datepicker)
When I select the date, it returns string like "2013-10-21T00:00:00.000Z"
But when I set this string to variable he doesn't react...
i tried this ways

```
 $scope.var1="2013-10-14T00:00:00.000Z";
 $scope.var1= {date: new Date("2013-10-14T00:00:00.000Z")};
 $scope.var1="08/10/2012";
```

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WRMU5NLOuzWALW0NN24F?p=preview)
How to send date to him?

And is there any way to interact with it?  Or i must use only var1 assigned as his model?

Answer (score 0):

The string like `2013-10-14T00:00:00.000Z` represents by `new Date()`.

To store form, you can do that by create custom directive:

**directive**

```
app.directive('datetimez', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

          element.datepicker({
            dateFormat:'dd/MM/yyyy',
          }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
             console.log(e.date);
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(e.date);
            scope.$apply();
          });
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="inputDatepicker" class="input-small" type="text" datetimez ng-model="var1" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" >
```

See demo <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GdhQYTto3m8msrCrj9HK?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: i change it via "push date" button press. ng-click of button calls function which sets $scope.var1, but nothing happens with datepicker... Or mb i don't understand you answer?

Comment: you can only use this form: `$scope.var1="2013-10-14T00:00:00.000Z";`

Comment: i tried it. you can see my func in plunker, but it doesn't change datepicker displayed date...

Comment: i want to use the datepicker from "angular strap".  "you can only use this form: $scope.var1="2013-10-14T00:00:00.000Z";" this doesnt work...

Comment: I changed your Plunker, added directive, hope it will help you

Comment: yes it helped a bit in understanding, now i enlighted that we can use 2 directives at 1 element! But about this datepicker i dont understand why it is so buggy, there is no way to send data to him correct way... In your plunker i added bs-datepicker directive back, ad when i press button var1 vecomes "08/10/2012" i press input, select same date and var1 becomes "2012-10-08T00:00:00.000Z", the solution probably is to add converting code in datetimez directive to convert  08/10/2012 to "2012-10-08T00:00:00.000Z" and set correc $modelValue... prity sick ....

Comment: directives are only place where you should write jQuery code. Its not buggy. However angular has today own elements and models and sure datepicker will be available soon.

Answer (score 0):

Hopfully this is helpful to someone else... I just spent 20 min looking for this.

HTML:

```
<input type="date" id="date" ng-model="object.date">
```

CONTROLLER:

```
.controller('yourController', function($scope) {
  $scope.object = {
    date: new Date()
  }
});
```